# How to clean GPU memory in tensorflow2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Now, in tensorflow2.0 a lot of things have changed.

I need to know if is there any way to clean the GPU memory whenever I want.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session)

Comment: Calling tf.keras.backend.clear_session() works ok sometimes.